# How to automatically Import Cost Data into Google Analytics 4 (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics-api

in Universal Google Analytics, I was able to import cost data via https://script.google.com.

I looked for a solutions also for GA4 but couldnt find.

Can you help find a solution for the GA4?